# How to synchronize the test execution within one file?

Tags: cypress

I want to visit the page once, and then execute multiple validations against the loaded page, organized in multiple tests. I don't want to reload the page with each and every test.

I have the following:

```js
describe('my first test', () => {
  it('should visit en!', () => {
    cy.visit('https://myurl.com')
    cy.contains('#the-element') #passes
  })
  it('should have basics', () => {
    cy.contains('#the-element') #fails, presumable because the page is not loaded
  })
```

How do I get the second cy.contains to pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `testIsolation` option off.

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    testIsolation: false,
  },
})
```

The default is on, which causes the browser to reset to `about:blank` between tests.

See https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation#Quick-Comparison

| testIsolation | beforeEach test |
| --- | --- |
| true | clears page by **visiting about:blank** |
| false | does not alter the current browser context |